# Div colliding css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my HTML/CSS code. I am working on a website for my dad, but there is something wrong, the code has two divs at the moment but they are colliding with each other.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Wil Lodewijks - Dutch Photography</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Menu -->
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="/index.html"><img id="logo" src="/style/logo.png"></a>
                <a class="menuitem selected" href="/videos">Foto's</a>
                <a class="menuitem" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </div>

        <!-- Main -->
        <div id="main">
            <h2>Welkom bij de foto galerij van Nederlands fotograaf Wil Lodewijks.</h2>
            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Menu */
    div#menu {
        background-color: #3e4040;
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* Main */
    div#main {
        background-color: #f03026;
    }

    /* Menu opmaak */
    /* Tekst */
    div#menu a.menuitem {
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Menu items */
    div#menu a.menuitem {
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
```

Comment: you made your #menu position:absolute, which removes it from document flow calculations.

Comment: @MarcB what should I set it to?

Comment: Off of what Marc pointed out, if you just need the `#menu` to be able to catch any children it has that ar `pos:abs`, set it to `position:relative;` instead. Without using a `top` or its ilk, `pos:rel` only causes it to catch child positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

The property `position: absolute` removes the `#menu` div from the document flow, so you will need to give `#main` a margin equal to the size of `#menu` in to avoid the overlap. Alternatively you could also not use `position: absolute` on that div, but that depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp for more information on the different options for this property.

Answer (score 0):

take the

```
position: absolute;
```

away in your menu

```
div#menu {
        background-color: #3e4040;
        position: absolute;    <<<<<<<this you have to take away
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
```

Comment: due to a lack of `top` and co. in the snippet we were shown, I'd suggest replacing it with `relative` instead of nixing it- something might be expecting `#menu` to catch it when it positions itself.

Comment: but i think it is a problem of the snippet because in https://jsfiddle.net/ it works

Comment: You misunderstand entirely. Replacing with `position: relative;` rather than removing all position will cause you to not lose if you have a child of `#menu` that has `position:absolute;`. That is what I was saying.

Comment: ah ok sorry yes you rigth my english is not the strongest but now i understand